# How can I solve the need for clicking a button twice before the component renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I click the "Next Step" button in the Info-component 'nothing' happens. Only after a second click the page navigates to the next component.

I understand it has to do with the async nature of useState and I think it is 'submitting' in the handleSubmit function that has not rendered yet when it is called.

I tried useEffect and other options, but cannot find a solution where both the validation system works and the next page renders after a single click.

app.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Menu from '../src/components/Menu/Menu';
import Info from '../src/components/Info/Info';
import Plan from '../src/components/Plan/Plan';
import AddOn from '../src/components/AddOn/AddOn';
import Summary from '../src/components/Summary/Summary';
import Confirm from '../src/components/Confirm/Confirm';
import Footer from '../src/components/Footer/Footer';
import PlanList from './PlanList.json';
import AddOnList from './AddOnList.json';

function App() {
    
  const [plans] = useState(PlanList);
  const [addOns]= useState(AddOnList);
  const [isMonthly, isYearly] = useState('Monthly');
  const [planPrice, setPlanPrice] = useState(0);
  const [planName, setPlanName] = useState('');
  const [summaryItems, setSummaryItems] = useState([]);
  const [addOnOne, setAddOnOne] = useState(false)
  const [addOnTwo, setAddOnTwo] = useState(false)
  const [addOnThree, setAddOnThree] = useState(false)
  const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState({name: "", email: "", phone: ""});
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);

  const validateValues = (inputValues) => {
    let errors = {};
    if (inputValues.name.length < 1) {
      errors.name = "This field is required";
    }
    if (inputValues.email.length < 1) {
      errors.email = "This field is required";
    }
    if (inputValues.phone.length < 1) {
      errors.phone = "This field is required";
    }
    return errors;
  };
  
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputFields({ ...inputFields, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
    
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setErrors(validateValues(inputFields));
    setSubmitting(true);   
  };

  const addPlanData = (plan) => {
    const planId = plans.find((x) => x.id === plan.id)
    const price = planId.price
    const name = planId.name
    setPlanName(name)
    isMonthly ?
    setPlanPrice(price.month) :
    setPlanPrice(price.year)    
  };

  const handleSwitch = () => {
    isYearly(!isMonthly)
  };

  const addOnOneClicked = () => {
    const exists = summaryItems.some(element => element.id === 1);
    if (!exists) {
      setSummaryItems((prev) => [...prev, addOns[0]])}
    else {
      setSummaryItems((prev) => [...prev.filter((element) => element.id !== 1 )])
    } 
    setAddOnOne(!addOnOne)  
  }

  const addOnTwoClicked = () => {
    const exists = summaryItems.some(element => element.id === 2);
    if (!exists) {
    setSummaryItems((prev) => [...prev, addOns[1]])}
    else {
      setSummaryItems((prev) => [...prev.filter((element) => element.id !== 2 )])
    } 
    setAddOnTwo(!addOnTwo)  
  }

  const addOnThreeClicked = () => {
    const exists = summaryItems.some(element => element.id === 3);
    if (!exists) {
    setSummaryItems((prev) => [...prev, addOns[2]])}
    else {
      setSummaryItems((prev) => [...prev.filter((element) => element.id !== 3 )])
    } 
    setAddOnThree(!addOnThree)  
  }
          
  const totalPrice = 
    isMonthly ? 
    summaryItems.reduce(
      (prevValue, currentValue) => prevValue + currentValue.price.month, 0) + planPrice :
    summaryItems.reduce(
      (prevValue, currentValue) => prevValue + currentValue.price.year, 0) + planPrice 

  
  return (
    <>
    <div className="main-container">
    <main>
      <Router>
      <Menu />
        <Routes>
          <Route 
            path="/" 
            element={<Info 
              inputFields={inputFields}
              errors={errors}
              submitting={submitting}
              handleChange={handleChange}
              handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
            />} />
          <Route 
            path="/Plan" 
            element={<Plan 
              isMonthly={isMonthly} 
              handleSwitch={handleSwitch}
              plans={plans}
              addPlanData={addPlanData}
              />} 
              />
          <Route 
            path="/AddOn" 
            element={<AddOn 
              isMonthly={isMonthly} 
              addOns={addOns}
              addOnOne={addOnOne}
              addOnTwo={addOnTwo}
              addOnThree={addOnThree}
              addOnOneClicked={addOnOneClicked}
              addOnTwoClicked={addOnTwoClicked}
              addOnThreeClicked={addOnThreeClicked}
              />
            } 
            />
          <Route 
            path="/Summary" 
            element={<Summary
              isMonthly={isMonthly}
              summaryItems={summaryItems}
              planPrice={planPrice}
              planName={planName}
              totalPrice={totalPrice}
              />} />
          <Route 
            path="/Confirm" 
            element={<Confirm />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </main>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <Footer />
    </footer>   
    </>
  );  
}

export default App;
```

button.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../Button/Button.css';


export default function Button( {errors, submitting} ) {
    
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const handleNextButton = (e) => {    
    if (submitting && Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && location.pathname === "/") {
      e.preventDefault()
      navigate('/Plan')
    }
    if (location.pathname === "/Plan") {
      navigate('/AddOn')
    }
    if (location.pathname === "/AddOn") {
      navigate('/Summary')
    }
    if (location.pathname === "/Summary") {
      navigate('/Confirm')
    }
  }
  
  const handleBackButton = () => {
    if (location.pathname === "/Plan") {
      navigate('/')
    }
    if (location.pathname === "/AddOn") {
      navigate('/Plan')
    }
    if (location.pathname === "/Summary") {
      navigate('/AddOn')
    }
  }

    return (
      <>
      <div className="button-container">
        <button 
          className={location.pathname === "/" ? "return-link invisible" : "return-link smallfont light bold"}
          onClick={handleBackButton}>Go Back
        </button>
        <button 
          className="button"
          type={location.pathname === "/" ? "submit" : "button"}
          onClick={handleNextButton} >Next Step
        </button> 
      </div>
      </>
    )
}
```

Comment: put  some console.log debugging in `handleNextButton` function to see what's happening

Comment: I think the problem is with how you are changing the button type to be 'submit' on the last step. Keep the type as same and handle the submission in the handleNextButton step itself.

Comment: Hi Tirth, can you show what you mean by "handle the submission in the handleNextButton step itself"?

Answer (score -1):

Here are some suggestions for improving your class component:

1. Use arrow functions instead of binding your methods in the constructor.

`Arrow functions` automatically bind this value to the class instance, so you don’t need to write extra code in the constructor.

2. Use `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentWillUpdate`.

componentWillUpdate is deprecated. componentDidUpdate is a safer and more reliable way to update your component based on props or state changes.

Now try this code with the suggested items above:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../Button/Button.css';

// Use a class declaration instead of a function
export default class Button extends Component {

  // Use arrow functions instead of binding methods in the constructor
  handleNextButton = (e) => {
    if (this.props.submitting && Object.keys(this.props.errors).length === 0 && this.props.location.pathname === "/") {
      e.preventDefault()
      navigate('/Plan')
    }
    if (this.props.location.pathname === "/Plan") {
      navigate('/AddOn')
    }
    if (this.props.location.pathname === "/AddOn") {
      navigate('/Summary')
    }
    if (this.props.location.pathname === "/Summary") {
      navigate('/Confirm')
    }
  }

  handleBackButton = () => {
    if (this.props.location.pathname === "/Plan") {
      navigate('/')
    }
    if (this.props.location.pathname === "/AddOn") {
      navigate('/Plan')
    }
    if (this.props.location.pathname === "/Summary") {
      navigate('/AddOn')
    }
  }

  // Use componentDidUpdate instead of componentWillUpdate
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Do something when props or state change
  }

  // Use render method to return JSX
  render() {
    return (
      // Use React.Fragment instead of an empty tag
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="button-container">
          <button
            className={this.props.location.pathname === "/" ? "return-link invisible" : "return-link smallfont light bold"}
            onClick={this.handleBackButton}>Go Back
          </button>
          <button
            className="button"
            type={this.props.location.pathname === "/" ? "submit" : "button"}
            onClick={this.handleNextButton} >Next Step
          </button>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

// Use default props and prop types to specify and validate your props
Button.defaultProps = {
  errors: {},
  submitting: false,
}

Button.propTypes = {
  errors: PropTypes.object,
  submitting: PropTypes.bool,
}
```

**Answer UPDATED**
This update is added based on the OP recent edit:

> ---

It's a good idea to switch from class method to functional method. You  can use hooks such as useContext, useReducer, useRef and custom hooks to access context/manage complex state or even create references and reusing logics, whilst a class component cannot use hooks at all.

Here is a possible functional react component that does the same thing as your class component:

Use a function declaration instead of a class:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../Button/Button.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function Button(props) {
 useEffect(() => {
    // Do something when state change
  }, [props]); // Add props as a dependency

  const handleNextButton = (e) => {
    if (props.submitting && Object.keys(props.errors).length === 0 && props.location.pathname === "/") {
      e.preventDefault()
      navigate('/Plan')
    }
    if (props.location.pathname === "/Plan") {
      navigate('/AddOn')
    }
    if (props.location.pathname === "/AddOn") {
      navigate('/Summary')
    }
    if (props.location.pathname === "/Summary") {
      navigate('/Confirm')
    }
  }

  const handleBackButton = () => {
    if (props.location.pathname === "/Plan") {
      navigate('/')
    }
    if (props.location.pathname === "/AddOn") {
      navigate('/Plan')
    }
    if (props.location.pathname === "/Summary") {
      navigate('/AddOn')
    }
  }

  return (
    // Use React.Fragment instead of an empty tag
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="button-container">
        <button
          className={props.location.pathname === "/" ? "return-link invisible" : "return-link smallfont light bold"}
          onClick={handleBackButton}>Go Back
        </button>
        <button
          className="button"
          type={props.location.pathname === "/" ? "submit" : "button"}
          onClick={handleNextButton} >Next Step
        </button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  errors: {},
  submitting: false,
}

Button.propTypes = {
  errors: PropTypes.object,
  submitting: PropTypes.bool,
}
```

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for your suggestions, but can the issue be solved using functional components? I am less familiar with class components.